# Why isn't my validation working in my template function for C++?

Tags: c++, validation

I have attempted to make a program which allows the user to input 2 values as integers and 2 as doubles, to find the maximum of the two, respectively, using template functions in C++. I can't seem to get my desired outcome when I try to validate the error as it doesn't take in the new input after the error message. The output is usually a '0' after re-entering the new number. I tried using the validation code from this YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kqJlkQCukk&t=666s

Here is the code I've been working with:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

template <typename E>
void errorA(E a) {
if (!std::cin.good())
{
    cout << "\n\nERROR! Faulty input! Try again!\n";

//clear stream
cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

    //get input again
    cout << "Enter NUMBER again: ";
    cin >> a;

    }
  }


  template <typename T>
  void maximum(T& a, T& b) {

    if (a > b) {
    cout << a << " is the maximum of these 2 numbers: " << a << " & " << b << endl;
    }
else if (b > a) {
    cout << b << " is the maximum of the 2 numbers: " << a << " & " << b << endl;
}
else if (a == b) {
    cout << "Both these numbers: " << a << " & " << b << ", are equal! " << endl;
}

}

int main() {

int a, b;
cout << "Please enter 2 integers to find its maximum.\n";
cout << "Enter 1st number: ";
cin >> a;
errorA (a);
cout << "Enter 2nd number: ";
cin >> b;
errorA( b);

 maximum(a, b);


double c, d;
cout << "\n\nPlease enter 2 doubles to find its maximum.\n";
cout << "Enter 1st number: ";
cin >> c;
errorA(c);
cout << "Enter 2nd number: ";
cin >> d;
errorA(d);

maximum(c, d);

}
```

Comment: your `errorA` template should return the new `a` value, since you are not passing by reference.

Comment: You must use a reference parameter for `errorA(...)` too, like you did with `maximum(...)` (where it isn't needed and should be removed)

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at the signature of the `errorA` method:

```
void errorA(E a);
```

Compare it to your maximum function:

```
void maximum(T& a, T& b);
```

Do you see the difference? It's in the ampersand (&) character - it makes the difference between passing by value and passing by reference (with &). For `errorA` to work as you expect it to, you need to pass *by reference* (`void errorA(E& a)`, so that the value entered in errorA is actually modifying the passed in variable, and not a copy of it local to the errorA function (which is what happens currently).

Note that the maximum function actually wouldn't need the pass-by-reference parameters, as the variables passed in as parameters are not modified in it.